# Get record for a key but display value for a separate key in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange

So I have a table which has a composite primary key for SHIP# & REF#. Each SHIP# has two codes for REF# which are BM and PO. BM field is mandatory but the PO field only gets populated when the user actually inputs something. So, a basic select would display something like this:

```
SHIP#           REF#    VALUE
000002          BM      20001836                      
000002          PO      020                           
000003          BM      20001834                      
000003          PO      8-694                         
000004          BM      20001835
```

Now, you will notice that shipment 000004 has only BM and no PO.

I want to display all shipments with PO's values. So, if the PO value is empty or doesn't exist like in case '000004', it should simply put '-'. Since the BM is mandatory you'll have to get all records where BM exists but display value of the PO field.

So, the output should be:

```
SHIP#           REF#    VALUE                     
000002          PO      020                           
000003          PO      8-694                         
000004          PO      -
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outer join against itself can do the job too. For example:

```
select a.ship, 'PO' as ref, coalesce(b.value, '-') as value
from t a
left join t b on b.ship = a.ship and b.ref = 'PO'
where a.ref = 'BM'
```

Result:

```
SHIP    REF  VALUE
------  ---  -----
000002  PO   020
000003  PO   8-694
000004  PO   -
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c3fd03658557158ff56c078e8a574834).

**EDIT - Find only BMs with no PO.**

You can use the same query and add the extra predicate `and b.ship is null` in it, as in:

```
select a.ship, 'PO' as ref, coalesce(b.value, '-') as value
from t a
left join t b on b.ship = a.ship and b.ref = 'PO'
where a.ref = 'BM' 
  and b.ship is null
```

Result:

```
SHIP    REF  VALUE 
------- ---- ----- 
000004  PO   -
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=1d4d25942a36ba9eb3757a30caea5b98).

Comment: That's perfect. But let's say I want to get those records which have BM but no PO, so like a query which will only output the ship# 000004. How would that query be structured?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ship#, 'PO' as ref#,
       max(case when ref# = 'PO' then value end) as value 
from t
group by ship#
```

This returns the `value` as `NULL` -- which seems like a very good choice.  If you really want `'-'`, then use `COALESCE()`:

```
select ship#, 'PO' as ref#,
       coalesce(max(case when ref# = 'PO' then value end), '-') as value 
from t
group by ship#
```

Comment: That's perfect. But let's say I want to get those records which have BM but no PO, so like a query which will only output the ship# 000004. How would that query be structured?

Comment: @HarshitArora . . . Then you would have a different question.  You should accept this answer and ask a new question.